# AJAX/jquery doesn't work on a returned PHP-Site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

my problem is the following:
I designed a Webpage using divs. Via Onlick on a link I fill a div with the output of a PHP-File (MySQL-Querys). This PHP-Site is called by a XMLHttpRequest-Function in JavaScript.
On the PHP-Site I want to use jQuery to dis-/enable Buttons and Textareas. These jQuery Requests doesn't work. If I call the PHP-Site directly in the Browser everything will work fine. Where's my mistake?

JavaScript to call the PHP-Site and fill the div:

```
function selected_...(nr)
{
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      document.getElementById("right_details_content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","/.../ajax_querys.php?id=selected_...&nr="+nr,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Output of PHP-Site:

```
if($row['anwendung'] == "...") {
            echo "<span>name:</span><input type=\"text\" id=\"name\" name=\"servername\" value=\"" . $row['rechner'] . "\" disabled><br><br>";
            echo "<span>wort:</span><input type=\"text\" id=\"word\" name=\"password\" value=\"" . $word . "\" disabled><br><br>";
            echo "<span>Bemerkung:</span><textarea id=\"right_details_content_textarea\" rows=\"5\" name=\"bemerkung\" disabled>" . $row['bemerkung'] . "</textarea><br><br><br><br><br>";
            echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"nr\" value=\"" . $row['nr'] . "\"><br>";
            echo "<div class=\"left\"><input type=\"button\" id=\"edit\" name=\"edit\" value=\"bearbeiten\"><input type=\"button\" id=\"cancel\" name=\"cancel\" value=\"abbrechen\" style=\"display: none;\"></div>";
            echo "<div class=\"center\"><input type=\"button\" id=\"save\" name=\"save\" value=\"speichern\" disabled></div>";
            echo "<div class=\"right\"><input type=\"button\" id=\"delete\" name=\"delete\" value=\"l&ouml;schen\"></div>";
```

Ajax-Part:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// alert('Fertig');
    $("#edit").click(function(){
// alert('Click');
        if($("#save").attr("disabled")) {
            $("#name").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#word").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#right_details_content_textarea").removeAttr("disabled");
            document.getElementById("edit").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("cancel").style.display = "inline";
            $("#save").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: wait. You used jQuery on effects, but does not use it in ajax request?

Comment: As Shivan pointed out, look into `$.ajax`

Comment: I see you've edited your question, and included "Ajax-part". May I point out that that isn't Ajax? Take a look here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Is the "Ajax-part" included in the calling page, or is it called from PHP page

Comment: The AJAX-Part is included in the html-file where the div is in and in the php-file. It makes no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what a mass question. well, i think since you are using jquery it is better to use $.ajax to request server.

something like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/.../ajax_querys.php?id=selected_...&nr=",
        type: "GET",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
    }).done(function(res){
      console.log(res);
      $("#right_details_content").html(res);
    }).fail(function(err){
       console.log(err);
    });                 
    });
```

check this, if doesn't work anyway, check request URL and limitation on your code.
good luck.

Comment: but how can i call this by clicking on a link?

Comment: @jonesk just in a trigger.`$('a').click(function(){...});`

Comment: ... but i have a list of servernames getting from a mysql database. at the moment i have a onclick for each link to a function. To this function i give the id of the server. this function calls a php script which give server-specific details back. how to do this in ajax?